# GWT SuggestBox Popup same size as Input Field

Tags: css, gwt, suggestbox

I tried to create a SuggestBox with GWT and everything worked correctly so far.
But I would like to have the Popup of the SuggestBox to have the same size as the Input Field, but I haven't found a way to do this.

I would be happy, if you could give me a tip.

Greetings
Kevin

Comment: If you found the solution for this from the below answers, accept and upvote the answers. If you got your own answer, put that down and accept it. This will help other users who are looking answers for similar type of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your SuggestBox has a fixed width, let say 200px, you can apply the following style

```
.gwt-SuggestBoxPopup .item{ width:  198px;}
```

Answer (score 8):

Create a custom class extending `DefaultSuggestonDisplay` and override `showSuggestions` method

```
import java.util.Collection;

import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Unit;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox.DefaultSuggestionDisplay;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox.SuggestionCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestOracle.Suggestion;

public class CustomSuggestionDisplay extends DefaultSuggestionDisplay
{
    @Override
    protected void showSuggestions( SuggestBox suggestBox, Collection< ? extends Suggestion> suggestions, boolean isDisplayStringHTML, boolean isAutoSelectEnabled, SuggestionCallback callback )
    {
        super.showSuggestions( suggestBox, suggestions, isDisplayStringHTML, isAutoSelectEnabled, callback );
        getPopupPanel().setWidth( ( suggestBox.getElement().getAbsoluteRight() - suggestBox.getAbsoluteLeft() ) + Unit.PX.getType() );
    }
}
```

Use the following suggest box consturctor

```
SuggestBox suggestBox = new SuggestBox( new MultiWordSuggestOracle(), new TextBox(), new CustomSuggestionDisplay() );
```

Comment: The problem is that de content item is not 100% width... so you cannot select it if you don't click over the item text. Do you know how to make suggestions 100% witdh? Thanks!